# Z3 Java Api for mkAnd

Tags: z3

How can I use mkAnd to join three terms.  For example, I have a1=1,a2=3,a3=10.  Now I want to use produce formula: (and (and a1=1 a2=3) a3=10).  I use mkAnd(a1,a2,a3), it only gives me the wrong formula (and a1=1 a2=3 a3=10).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `wrong'? mkAnd(t1, t2, t3) produces the formula (and t1 t2 t3), which is exactly what it is supposed to do. You could also use mkAnd(mkAnd(t1, t2), t3), but semantically that's equivalent.

Comment: hi christoph, if they are semantically equivalent. then that's fine. But what I want to do is trying to add extra formuals to my original existing smt2 file, and ask solver to check sat again. But, every time I add extra formula to prevent all previous assignments from being found again.  I get the model representation wrong.  I am using getModel() method, then getConstDecls() and getConstInterp().  But it seems the model doesn't give me the full representation here.  That's why i doubt the mkand function. do you have any idea how to get a full model representation from 2nd,3rd...nth solving?

Comment: That approach should work just fine, could you perhaps give me an example of where it goes wrong?

Comment: Yes, that should work fine (assuming that you add an constraint that represents constant[i] != expr afterwards). I meant, can you give me an example where this strategy fails?

Comment: Hi Christoph, here is an example:     while (z3Solver.check()==Status.SAT){model = z3Solver.getModel(); constants=model.getConstDecls(); for (int i=0;i<constants.length;i++){expr = model.getConstInterp(constant[i]) z3Solver.add(Negate(exprs)) Symbol sym = constants[i].getName(); BoolExpr b = ctx.mkEq(ctx.mkBoolConst(sym),expr)}}. Negate(exprs) is just the function for conjoining and negating my previous assignments.  The first solution is fine, but the 2nd solution, the solver only returns me a partial assignment with error information about index. Maybe I shouldn't create new BoolExpr ?

Comment: So I have a formula x1 or x2, and the first solving returns a model of x1=false and x=true.  The second solving returns x1=true only with no interpretation for x2.  Now, I switch to use model.eval, but it still miss some interpretations.

Comment: I found out what problem is, the program itself is correct. All i need to do is set parameter auto-config = true. Now, Z3 seems to return me the full model now.